# Foreign key constraint error when adding through migrating

Tags: foreign-keys, migration, laravel-4

I am trying to create a foreign key constraint between my two tables on Laravel 4, User and GP. A user can be associated with many GPs. The foreign key is 'Practice_ID' in the users table, which associates with the ID in the GP table.

```
    public function up()
{

    // Creates GP table
    Schema::create('gp', function($ta)
    {
        $ta->bigIncrements('id');
        $ta->string('address_1');
        $ta->string('address_2');
        $ta->string('address_3');
        $ta->string('post_code');
        $ta->timestamps();
    });

    // Creates the users table
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('confirmation_code');
        $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
        $table->bigInteger('practice_id');
        $table->foreign('practice_id')->references('id')->on('gp');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Creates password reminders table
    Schema::create('password_reminders', function($t)
    {
        $t->string('email');
        $t->string('token');
        $t->timestamp('created_at');
    });

}
```

The error I am getting is:

> [Exception]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'doctor.#sql-3ac_a4' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `users` add
>   constraint users_practice_id_foreign foreign key (`practice_id`)
>   references `gp` (`id`)) (Bindings: array (
>   ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`err 150` is most likely a data type mismatch.

delcare the foregin key as an unsigned int in the `users` table:

```
$table->integer('practice_id')->unsigned();
```

Also verify your db engine is INNODB that supports FK constraints

Comment: Hi A.O, I've made the adjustments (see amended code above), however, on php artisan migrate:refresh, the same error still appears.

Comment: change it back to just regular `increments` in the gp table and try the above code in the users table