# How to manage relationships(fk) of models?

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship, laravel-artisan

I know how to create a model - `php artisan make:model nameofmodel`, i know that in the migration of the model i have to declare what columns will the table have:

```
class CreateNameofmodelTable extends Migration {

     /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function up()
     {
        Schema::create('nameofmodels', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

   /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::drop('nameofmodels');
   }
}
```

But if i want to relate two models using a FK, what are the configurations i have to set in the migration file or in the model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have another model User with table name `users`. you can have relationship defined between `addresses` and `users` as following,

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addresses', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('add1');
            $table->string('add2');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('contact_no');
            $table->enum('is_primary',['yes','no'])->default('no');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

In User model class,

```
class User extends Model {
   /**
   * The table associated with the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
    }

}
```

in Address class

```
class Address extends Model {
    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
   protected $table = 'addresses';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

More detailed information about creating table can be found on Official [Schema Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema) on Laravel. And More information about Relation ship [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

**UPDATE**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571818/laravel-5-migration-error-related-to-foreign-key) question, you will have to create referenced table first before referencing table. In our case, `users` must exists before you run migration to create `addresses` table.

Simple Use-case

suppose, in controller you want to find out how many addresses particular users have, you can do like following,

```
$addressCount = User::find($userId)->addresses->count();
```

Please note  `User::find($userId)->addresses` returns collection of related models while `User::find($userId)->addresses()` returns object of type `HasMany`

you can also traverse collection as below,

```
foreach(User::find($userId)->addresses as $address)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($address);
}
```

On the other side, you can get user associated with particular address as below,

```
$user = Address:find($addressId)->user; //returns object of type `User`
echo $user->first_name;
```

following will **not** work

```
$user = Address:find($addressId)->user(); //returns object of type `belongsTo`
echo $user->first_name;
```

Note, above `Address:find($addressId)->user` will not return collection but a single object of class User. This is because a `belongsTo` relationship.

I hope I made things clear for you. But nothing as good as official [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/).

[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/) videos are even better to get on with Laravel.

Comment: Could you explain what happens in the Users and Address classes?, i mean, i understand that the functions `adresses` and `user` has the functionality of telling what kind of relation is between the tables, but when are the functions called?

Comment: Im getting an error 150, its referenced to the FK, what i'm not sure is if laravel handle the migrations in the order they are created or evaluating if a table must exist before anther because of the fks

Answer (score 0):

you cal use like this...

```
class CreateNameofmodelTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nameofmodels', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
Schema::create('your table name', function(Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('nameofmodels');
}

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('nameofmodels');
}

}
```

check it..may be it is working perfectly....